# Disabling a link until a series of checkboxes are checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, licensing

I'm trying to figure out how to disable the following link until a series of 4 or 5 checkboxes have been selected.

```
 <input type="image" src="/wp-content/themes/happy/images/add-to-cart.png" name="Buy" class="wpsc_buy_button" id="product_<?php echo wpsc_the_product_id(); ?>_submit_button" onclick="window.location='http://example.com/store/checkout/';"/>
```

Thanks!

I'm also kind of retarded when it comes to js and jquery, so the simpler the better, please. I would like to have all the code right there near the element, and not off in a different location, even though that might be the "preferred" method.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: 4 *or* 5? which is it? 4 or 5? and does it matter which ones are checked or just that there are a certain number of them?

Comment: Okay, so actually it's going to be 12. And ALL of them must be checked in order for the image to submit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
<input type="image" src="/wp-content/themes/happy/images/add-to-cart.png" name="Buy" class="wpsc_buy_button" id="product_<?php echo wpsc_the_product_id(); ?>_submit_button" onclick="if($(this).data("enabled")){window.location='http://example.com/store/checkout/';}"/>
```

And on check box click do this

```
$("input").click(function(){

   //Here check for this checkbox and all other series of checkbox, if they are checked then
   $("img[name=Buy]").data("enabled", true);
   //else
   $("img[name=Buy]").data("enabled", false);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have jquery referenced, change your onclick method to something like;

```
onclick="if($('.checkboxClass').not(':checked').length > 0) window.location='http://example.com/store/checkout/'; else {alert('please tick all the checkboxes'); return 0};
```

Then add the "checkboxClass" (or whatever class you choose) to all of your checkboxes

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checkboxClass" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" class="checkboxClass" value="2" />
```

And so on.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the following form:

```
 <form method="post" action="" class="my-form">
     <p>
         <input type="checkbox" /> First item
     </p>
     <p>
         <input type="checkbox" /> Second item
     </p>
     <p> 
         <input type="image" src="..." />
     </p>
 </form>
```

Use jQuery to check on form submit

```
 $(function() {
     $(".my-form").submit(function() { 
         if ($(".my-form input[type=checkbox]:checked").length < 1)
         {
             alert("You must select at least one checkbox to proceed.");
             return false;
         }
     }
 }
```